# Как достать из natasha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, natasha

НЕ могли бы вы сказать, как можно достать text и pos из проанализированного текста

```
[DocToken(stop=9, text='Появление', pos='NOUN', feats=<Inan,Nom,Neut,Sing>), DocToken(start=10, stop=13, text='ООН', pos='PROPN', feats=<Inan,Gen,Fem,Sing>), DocToken(start=14, stop=18, text='было', pos='AUX', feats=<Imp,Neut,Ind,Sing,Past,Fin,Act>)]

появление NOUN
ООН PROPN

tt = 'Появление ООН было обусловлено целым рядом объективных факторов'    

from natasha import (
    Segmenter,
    NewsEmbedding,
    NewsMorphTagger,
    Doc)

segmenter = Segmenter()

emb = NewsEmbedding()
morph_tagger = NewsMorphTagger(emb)
doc = Doc(tt)
doc.segment(segmenter) 
doc.tag_morph(morph_tagger)
doc.tag_morph(morph_tagger)
doc.tokens
```

Comment: А откуда тот список взяли? Там есть объекты и скорее всего можно напрямую у объектов списка запросить те поля. Можете привести минимальный пример, чтобы можно было самостоятельно запустить? :)

Comment: @gil9red подправила

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло сделать ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из `doc.tokens` можно взять список токенов, каждый токен это объект `DocToken`, у которого можно запросить атрибуты `pos` и `text`

Пример:

```
from natasha import Segmenter, NewsEmbedding, NewsMorphTagger, Doc


tt = 'Появление ООН было обусловлено целым рядом объективных факторов'

segmenter = Segmenter()

emb = NewsEmbedding()
morph_tagger = NewsMorphTagger(emb)
doc = Doc(tt)
doc.segment(segmenter)
doc.tag_morph(morph_tagger)

for token in doc.tokens:
    print(token.pos, token.text)
```

Результат:

```
NOUN Появление
PROPN ООН
AUX было
VERB обусловлено
ADJ целым
NOUN рядом
ADJ объективных
NOUN факторов
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = Doc(text)
doc[0].__dict__['text']
```

но это грубо, как увидел из справки нужно doc.spans.text